# Python/Biopython - Replace amino acid residue on MSA with "z" from a list of unaligned positions

Tags: fasta, python, proteins

I'm trying to programmatically replace a set of amino acid residues on an MSA with a "Z" from a list of unaligned positions. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Input: a list of unaligned positions for each sequence + an MSA
Output: an MSA with those unaligned positions on the aligned MSA replaced with a Z for each sequence.

I have a multiple sequence alignment i'm working with and a list of sites on that alignment that are glycosylated. I was trying to run a script that would take the input of the positions as a list of characters along with the MSA to replace the Nth character with a "Z" to easily visualize the sites. So essentially if I feed it the following sequence

```
M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K
```

and positions

```
2, 5, 10, 11, 14
```

it should spit back

```
M----ZFLZFLCLZZFAZAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K
```

Comment: Hi @DannyMorales and welcome. This is likely fairly easy to do, but the question is difficult to understand. Any clarity would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Michael! Thanks for the reply. I have a multiple sequence alignment i'm working with and a list of sites on that alignment that are glycosylated. I was trying to run a script that would take the input of the positions as a list of characters along with the MSA to replace the Nth character with a "Z" to easily visualize the sites. 

So essentially if I feed it the following sequence "M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K" and positions "2, 5, 10, 11, 14" it should spit back "M----ZFLZFLCLZZFAZAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K"

Comment: Understand, what you need to do is update your question with the information above and then provide the code you have so far. The obvious choice here is biopython AlignIO

Comment: Could you please show your code, so that is clear what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The code is

```
import re

pos = [2, 5, 10, 11, 14]
newseq = []
prot = 'M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K'
count = 0
for n,s in enumerate(prot):    
    if str(s) == '-':
        count += 1
        newseq.append('-')
    else:
        if (n + 1 - count) in pos:
            s = re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]', 'Z', s)
        newseq.append(s)
print(''.join(newseq))
```

output

> M----ZFLZFLCLZZFAZAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K

Precisely as requested, apologies for the delay.

Happy to explain why it works - its just a couple of Python tricks and a method. It must be run under Python 3 (unlikely to work in Python 2) and probably >3.6.

BTW I normally avoid `re` for complicated reasons but its easy, hence its here.

---

As @gaspanic has pointed out `re` is not only unnecessary it will slow the code (`re` is very inefficient). It is in fact one of the 'legendary inefficiencies' of Python. Thus removing it ...

```
# variable declarations omitted
newseq = list()
count = 0
for n,s in enumerate(prot):    
    if str(s) == '-':
        count += 1
        newseq.append('-')
    else:
        if (n + 1 - count) in pos:
            s = 'Z'
        newseq.append(s)
print(''.join(newseq))
```

Same output.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, without the need for `re`:

```
seq = 'M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K'
pos = [2, 5, 10, 11, 14]

new_seq = []
count = 0
for s in seq:
    if s == "-":
        new_seq.append(s)
    else:
        count += 1
        if count in pos:
            new_seq.append('Z')
        else:
            new_seq.append(s)

print(''.join(new_seq))
```

Result:

```
M----ZFLZFLCLZZFAZAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K
```

Comment: Thanks @gaspanic. You are right `re` is very slow and removing is of course the better solution altogether. I came to coding via Perl so I tend to over regex and `re` is one the downsides of Python.

Comment: @M__, to be honest I didn't know ```re``` was particularly slow in Python. In any case, I think that if efficiency is an issue, it would also be important to define the final size of the ```new_seq``` list beforehand (e.g. ```[None]*len(seq)```), and then replace the ```None```s as one loops over ```seq```.

Comment: Hi @gaspanic its very famous for it. It should be compiled via `re.compile` but its still a problem.
The inbuilt regex - `split` `replace` that sort of thing - is usually used instead not for functionality (it ain't as good at all) but performance. 
Predefining the list size - I will look into that in detail, thanks and do some tests and timings. I'm well aware for `C` and `Cython` it is important. 
If I'm doing `re` I parallelise it.

Comment: ... okay I tried predefining the list but didn't noticeably improve in my code. deque is another way in. Would make a good question.

Comment: Yes, looks like you're right. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63600055/8861903 . I guess I must have inherited that idea from other languages (or I'm just plain wrong).

Comment: Thanks @gaspanic those timings were better than mine. I'll take another look later. It could be the data set size, this 'data set' is very small and there could be an overhead.

Comment: @M__ I actually tried extending the sequence 100000x, but the difference was still minimal. I even removed the if statements to see if that was the bottleneck, but still not much difference. It appears that the explanation lies in how Python allocates memory to lists :).

Comment: Hi @gaspanic as promised I've placed a question here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19506/improving-list-speed-glycosylation-example

Comment: Great, thx for taking the time! :)

Comment: Hi @gaspanic I've placed a 'final answer' in the thread https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19506/improving-list-speed-glycosylation-example . This combines an `iterator` with a `list comprehension` ... Many thanks for your input.