# Improving list speed: glycosylation example

Tags: python, phylogenetics, phylogeny, algorithms, benchmarking

I discussed a question with @gaspanic [Python/Biopython - Replace amino acid residue on MSA with "z" from a list of unaligned positions](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14625/python-biopython-replace-amino-acid-residue-on-msa-with-z-from-a-list-of-una)
. The issue emerged was speeding up lists in Python. The solutions we discussed were

1. Raw code
2. Predefining a list size
3. `deque`

| 1. @gaspanic | my code | 2. @gaspanic | my code | 3. @gaspanic | my code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.45-3.48 | 7.17-7.2 | 4.38-4.85 | 7.09-7.23 | 3.44-3.53 | 7.21-7.39 |

Run timings are seconds (3 replicated) above with @gaspanic's code being faster.

What improvements would speed this up?

Here I extended the data set

```
from itertools import repeat
def iterit(x):
    seq = 'M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K'
    return ''.join(list(repeat(seq, x)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seqE3 = iterit(2800) # length is 201600
    seqE4 = iterit(28000) # length is 2016000
    seqE5 = iterit(280000) # length is 20160000
```

@gaspanic code

```
for seqbit in [seqE3,seqE4,seqE5]:
    seq = seqbit
    pos = [2, 5, 10, 11, 14]    
    new_seq = []
    count = 0
    for s in seq:
        if s == "-":
            new_seq.append(s)
        else:
            count += 1
            if count in pos:
                new_seq.append('Z')
            else:
                new_seq.append(s)
   # print(''.join(new_seq))
```

My code:

```
# same variables and loop structure
newseq = list()
count = 0
for n,s in enumerate(prot):    
    if str(s) == '-':
        count += 1
        s = '-'
    else:
        if (n + 1 - count) in pos:
            s = 'Z'
    newseq.append(s)
# print(''.join(newseq))
```

Predefining lists code (additional counter needed for @gaspanic's code:

```
# same variables and loop structure
new_seq = [] * len(seq)
count = 0
for n,s in enumerate(prot):    
    if str(s) == '-':
        count += 1
        s = '-'
    else:
        if (n + 1 - count) in pos:
            s = 'Z'
    newseq[n] = s
```

Deque code simply any of the above substituting

```
newseq = list()
```

with

```
from collections import deque 
newseq = deque()
```

Suggestions for efficiency improvements welcome.

A solution in `Cython` code would be cool. `PyPI` is not sought here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by saying that Python is inherently slow and this feels like a case of perhaps unnecessary optimisation. With that in mind here are my suggested (untested) optimisations of @gaspanic code:

```
pos = {2, 5, 10, 11, 14} # make pos a set for O(1) member testing, and don't define inside the loop
for seq in (seqE3,seqE4,seqE5): # Define seq here rather than inside the loop, and use an immutable tuple instead of a mutable list  
    new_seq = []
    count = 0
    for s in seq:
        if s == "-":
            new_seq.append(s)
        else:
            count += 1
            new_seq.append('Z' if count in pos else s) # use ternary operator
```

Comment: Thanks, the tuple did add speed, particularly tuple the iterator output. Using a `set` (the `{}` brackets) was a good solution and reduced runtime by ~0.5 seconds, which I'd not considered. It was better than `tuple` in this example. Repositioning `pos` adds a tiny amount, but agree its better practice and depends on the size of `pos` (in this case its small). Happy to discuss `Python`'s slow speed in a summary.

Answer (score 1):

Huge thanks to @Chris_Rands, this solution increases runtime by ~ 0.5 seconds uniformly across all coded solutions, so this code has a runtime of just over 3 seconds runtime on the benchmark machine. I incorporated my solution with @Chris_Rands solution and the final runtime I got was:

@gaspanic

> 1.7 - 1.8 seconds

This being twice the fastest speed in the question and four times the speed of my raw code.

My code

> 4.4 - 4.5 seconds

However a unique combination is needed:

1. `tuple` (Chris Rands)
2. `set` - important (Chris Rands)
3. an `iterator`
4. a `list comprehension`

In particular 3. and 4. are needed in combination. This is explained below.

```
def iterit(x):
    seq = 'M----KFLAFLCLLGFANAQ-------------D-GKCG----TLSNKSPS--------------------K'
    return tuple(''.join(list(repeat(seq, x))))

def mIterit(seqE3,seqE4,seqE5):
    pos = {2, 5, 10, 11, 14}
    for seqbit in (seqE3,seqE4,seqE5):
        seq = seqbit
        count = 0
        # loc = 0
        for s in seq:
            if s == "-":
                yield '-'
            else:
                count += 1
                if count in pos:
                    yield 'Z'
                else:
                    yield s

f __name__ == '__main__':
    
    seqE3 = iterit(2800) # length is 201600
    seqE4 = iterit(28000) # length is 2016000
    seqE5 = iterit(280000) # length is 20160000
    
    listComp = [i for i in mIterit(seqE3,seqE4,seqE5)]
```

The list comprehension (variable `listComp`) is the very last line and is crucial to the solution otherwise there is little increase in speed to @Chris_Rand's code. This alternative is to replace the last line with:

```
newseq = list()
for i in mIterit(seqE3,seqE4,seqE5):
    newseq.append(i)
```

A simple:

```
for i in mIterit(seqE3,seqE4,seqE5):
    pass
```

Is the same speed as the list comprehension, but its of no value because the output isn't saved to anything.

I was impressed by the interaction between the `iterator` and `list comprehension`. The other notable influence on speed is the `set` described by @Chris_Rand.

How does it work? `tuples` do increase speed by removing some functional of a `list` (immutability). Here the gain is small. Placing the `pos` variable outside the loop speaks for itself (0.1 seconds gain). `set` is interesting.

The `iterator` spews out a stream of results via `yield` which is where it attains its speed. The problem is capturing that stream outside the `iterator` is expensive. However `list comprehensions` are faster than standard loops and in this scenerio carry little/no detectable overhead. I was impressed. Up to this point I thought `list comprehensions` were a bit faster and a lot 'cooler' than loops. I hadn't understood there was a synergy with an `iterator`.

Is it all worth it? `Python` can easily achieve faster run times than `Java` using Cython but I will place the discussion in the *chat* forum next week.